# PyDev tells "error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version",but command line works fine

Tags: python, cuda, pydev, nvidia

My configuration like this:

```
Ubuntu        16.04
Java          1.8
Python        2.7.12
Caffe         1.0
Cuda          8.0
Nvidia driver 375-66
PyDev         5.7.0.201704111357

And I tried to run this in bash:
```

https://github.com/ZheC/Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation/tree/master/testing/python

by

```
python -m Demo
```

It works fine,but when try to run from eclipse-pydev,got this error:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E0606 09:34:43.905447 15924 common.cpp:114] Cannot create Cublas handle. Cublas won't be available.
0
E0606 09:34:43.905640 15924 common.cpp:121] Cannot create Curand generator. Curand won't be available.
F0606 09:34:43.905845 15924 common.cpp:152] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)  CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I think this problem comes from that I start up OS with nvidia driver then switchs to intel like this:
   [image]

This is what I want due to hope to use embeded intel VC to handle OS related work,and leave Nvidia VC for caffe(a deep learning framework) jobs.The
question is :

Why,for same python wrapped caffe job,does command line work fine but PyDev give the these error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the tips from @Fabio Zadrozny

Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter->Click Environment->New

```
create a env variable:
Name:LD_LIBRARY_PATH   Value:as in you system env
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually this means that you have some environment variable in your command line that's not replicated in PyDev.

The usual fix is to launch Eclipse from the command line, so that it inherits the variables set there.